# Forcing javascript text selection to end when mouse leaves window

Tags: javascript, jquery, awesomium

We're currently running a web-app in an awesomium frame, but the same(ish) thing happens in stock Chrome as well:

A user can select an amount of text on page, but if they mouseup when the cursor is *outside* the window, the 'selection' event never actually 'ends'. When they type or move the mouse back into the window, it acts like `mouseup` never happened, and changes the selection.

I've tried forcing a `mouseup` event on the given input element when the window observes a `mouseleave`, but that doesn't seem to have worked, the only thing that cancels the selection event is physically clicking the mouse (unfortunately `.click()` doesn't work either)!

Am I missing a particular event that needs firing on a specific element, or some particular method I can call to end a selection?

Any help massively appreciated!

---

**Edit**: one of the issues is that because the selection never finishes, typing constantly overwrites itself.

With any text input, type something in then click at the end and drag back (selecting all text) but DON'T release your mouse button, if you then type you'll see one of the issues we're encountering.

How can I *stop* that selection event from happening (in this instance, when the mouse leaves the window)?

Comment: On `mouseleave` on the `window` you could try `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).collapse(false)`. Personally I can't repro this on Chrome Windows

Comment: Collapse sort of works - it deselects the selection - but moving the mouse back in still continues selecting. I'm not sure how to get a demo up anywhere.. if I can work something out I'll add it to the question!